# any softwares - free or not where i can test my website design for different browsers?

Tags: css

i have a windows 7 64 bit and my internet explorer is 9.I have no idea how to test my websites for ie 6 and ie7. I wanted to know if there are some good softwares both free or not which i can use to check my website compatibility for the different browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interactive or advanced use, you'll have to have the browser on your machine. To get older IEs on Windows, use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). For 100% of the configuration, you need a VM, like the [IE VMs provided by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575).

Alternatively, if a single picture is enough, have a look at [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) where you can get a screenshot of your website rendered by the browsers of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Check out IETester

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Not really a programming question though :)

Also there are some free online services which displays the different rendering of brwosers (not sure whether it is accurate though).

Comment: agreed - this would be more appropriate for webmasters

Answer (score 1):

For IE: [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). Most other browsers have Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

[DebugBar / IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) will allow you to render your page in versions of IE back to 6 (maybe 5). Its pretty easy to use, and yes, its free. <strike>The best option I've found</strike>. A good option I've found. Lol

Comment: Actually, nothing is better than testing in the browser itself.  As pointed out by @phihag, MS provides VPC for free along with [free virtual hard drive images](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11575) just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

https://browserlab.adobe.com/ - Its free for all users until April 2012.

Includes an Onion Preview where it overlays two browsers over top of each other, and as well as a firefox plugin so you can view local versions of pages.

Browsers it shows:

- Chrome 10 - Windows
- Chrome 11 - Windows
- Firefox 3 - OS X
- Firefox 3 -Windows
- Firefox 3.6 - OS X
- Firefox 3.6 - Windows
- Firefox 4 - Windows
- IE 6 - Windows
- IE 7 - Windows
- IE 8 - Windows
- IE 9 - Windows
- Safari 4 - OS X
- Safari 5 - OS X

Comment: I just tried it.  I'm very underwhelmed... for the amount of hassle and resources required just to get it loaded, all it does is render a static screen-shot.  We're not in the 90's anymore... pages probably require user interaction before potential CSS or JavaScript issues are revealed.

Comment: I guess adobe tools for the most part are tailored more to designers than developers.

Comment: I don't know what that means, because without any programming, the graphics will likely look identical in all browsers.  The individual responsible for cross-browser consistency is typically the programmer (developer).